# SwiftUI List with Selection and onTapGesture Interfering with Each Other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I have a List that needs to support both selection of items and handling double tap gestures on those items. However, I'm facing an issue where enabling onTapGesture seems to interfere with the list's selection functionality. When the tap gesture is enabled, the selection doesn't work as expected. Disabling onTapGesture makes the selection work again.

Here is a minimal example of my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItemId: UUID?
    @State private var items: [ListItem] = ListItem.sampleItems

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItemId) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // Handle tap gesture here
                        print("Item tapped: \(item.name)")
                    }
                    .tag(item.id) // This is important for selection to work
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Optional: Perform any initial setup
        }
    }
}

struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String

    static var sampleItems: [ListItem] {
        [
            ListItem(id: UUID(), name: "Item 1"),
            ListItem(id: UUID(), name: "Item 2"),
            ListItem(id: UUID(), name: "Item 3")
        ]
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Ideally, I would like the list to support both item selection and handling tap gestures without interfering with each other. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any recommendations on how to approach this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the list to also change selection when `onTapGesture` is triggered, you can simply programmatically "select" the item in the `onTapGesture` closure:

```
Text(item.name)
    .onTapGesture {
        selectedItemId = item.id // selects the tapped item
        print("Item tapped: \(item.name)")
    }
    .tag(item.id)
```

Comment: thanks! but I need to use native list selection, to make multiple selection, keyboard selection, etc

Comment: @ManeManero How does `onTapGesture` affect keyboard selection? They are completely unrelated things. For multiple selection, you can do this in a similar way, i.e. adding/removing `item` from the list of selected items, depending on whether `item` is already in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Manually selecting the cell most probably should solve your problem (as described in @Sweeper's answer). Although you might need to change your row content (in your case the `Text`) so it fills the whole row.

As an alternative approach you can subscribe to the `selectedItemId` by using `Combine`.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItemId: UUID?
    @State private var items: [ListItem] = ListItem.sampleItems

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItemId) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .tag(item.id) // This is important for selection to work
            }
        }
        .onReceive(Just($selectedItemId)) { _ in
            if let selectedItemId {
                print("item is selected with id: \(selectedItemId)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So every time the user selects a cell the `onReceive` block will be called (even when the user taps the same cell multiple times).

Comment: thanks a log ©Sweeper and @narek.sv, but the problem with both solutions is that the native selection is lost, so things like multiple selection becomes complex... is there a way to keep the native selection, while still being able to double click? this is same as Apple Photos app for ex: select a photo, double click to open

Comment: Actually in this case I have nothing to do with selection process itself. I just observe when the selection changes. Could you please clarify what you mean saying that native selection is lost?